# No matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker

I've cloned the repository https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images. Now when I am trying to run one of the images I am getting error message `no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries` . I am trying to follow this blog http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/starting-with-docker-and-sitecore.

Any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need experimental features but you need Windows containers (as @x3mxray wrote) and an updated Windows. I see that it is failing on windows/servercore:ltsc2019, you can see the compability table at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility - Windows 10 1809 or newer should work

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below steps,

1. Right-click on the docker icon and click on "*Switch to Windows container*"
2. Open the docker for the desktop
3. Go to settings
4. Select the "*Docker Engine*" Tab
5. Update the below params in the *Docker Daemon*

   {"experimental": true}
6. Hit the *Apply* button and *restart the docker*.

[image: Screenshot - Docker Engine Daemon]

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that you switch mode to **Windows container**
[image]

2) Try to switch **Experimental features** under the Daemon Docker Settings (check if unchecked and vice versa). Restart docker.
[image]

Comment: @himanshu-agarwal, did it help?